# SSRS 2008 IIF Multi condition syntax

Tags: ssrs-2008

So far I have the following expression that works correctly:
*SUM(IIF(Fields!operation_type.Value="Motor",0,Fields!NbPieces_ref.Value))*

however, How is the syntax if I want to add more conditions ? On top of 
*Fields!operation_type.Value="Motor"* another condition would be 
*Fields!operation_type.Value="Break"*

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the SWITCH function.  It'll return the value of the first condition satisfied.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!operation_type.Value = "Motor", 0, Fields!operation_type.Value = "Break", 3)
```

Hope this helps.